# Ajax textbox spell check

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I check using Javascript if word entered in a textbox is spelled right. I am looking for some website like [wictionary](http://wiktionary.com) where I send the word to and receive response back as true or false.

There are few things like using URL: `http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=categories&titles=' + word;`
But the problem is these are too complicated to understand. I am looking for a simple solution.